# Applying flex wipedown effect dynamically

Tags: apache-flex

The panel is added OK, but the wipedown effect dont work, what's wrong? Ty!

```
import mx.controls.Alert;
import spark.components.Panel;
import mx.effects.Effect;
import mx.effects.WipeDown;

private function aoClickar():void{
    Alert.show("Mundo");
}

private function addPanel():void{
    var novo:Panel = new Panel();
    var efeito:Effect = new WipeDown();

    novo.width=180;
    novo.height=115;
    novo.x=0;
    novo.y=0;
    novo.id="panel13";

    efeito.target=novo;

    this.addElement(novo);

    efeito.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using the spark `Wipe` effect instead.  The MX effects use addChild which is not supported for spark controls, so you need to use the new spark effects.

Something like this :

```
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            import spark.components.Panel;
            import spark.effects.Fade;
            import spark.effects.Wipe;

            private function aoClickar():void{
                Alert.show("Mundo");
            }

            private function addPanel():void{
                var novo:Panel = new Panel();
                var efeito:Wipe = new Wipe();

                novo.width=180;
                novo.height=115;
                novo.x=0;
                novo.y=0;

                this.addElement(novo);

                efeito.target=novo;
                efeito.duration=2000;
                efeito.direction="right";           

                efeito.play();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking me to a correct direction, but the code still dont working.

Comment: The spark Wipe effect is designed for use with state transitions.  You can use it outside of that context but you will need to provide the bitmapFrom and bitmapTo values manually.